# SQL: Retrieving data from two tables via a 3rd linking key table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "families" (
    "id_family" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Family" TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE "levels" (
    "id_levels" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Level" TEXT UNIQUE,
    "Description" TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE "level_families" (
    "id_levels" INTEGER REFERENCES "levels" ("id_levels"),
    "id_family" INTEGER REFERENCES "families" ("id_family")
);

INSERT INTO "families" ( "id_Family","Family" ) VALUES ( '1','Work' );
INSERT INTO "families" ( "id_Family","Family" ) VALUES ( '2','Hobbies' );
Insert Into "levels" ("id_levels", "level") Values ('1', 'Beginner');
Insert Into "levels" ("id_levels", "level") Values ('2', 'Elementary');
Insert Into "level_families" ("id_levels", "id_family") Values ('1', '1');
Insert Into "level_families" ("id_levels", "id_family") Values ('1', '2');
Insert Into "level_families" ("id_levels", "id_family") Values ('2', '2');
```

I'm trying to retrieve all levels with their families concatenated, example output:

Beginner: Work, Hobbies

Elementary: Hobbies

Using the following code:

```
SELECT t.level, f.family
FROM families f
JOIN (
        SELECT lf.id_family, l.level
        FROM  level_families lf
                JOIN levels l
                ON lf.id_levels=l.id_levels
    ) t
ON f.id_family=t.id_family;
```

I'm getting:

Beginner: Work

Beginner: Hobbies

Elementary: Hobbies

Comment: Show the desired output for the example data.

Comment: Updated with desired output. I apologise for the lack of initial details in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.level, f.family
FROM families f
    JOIN (
            SELECT lf.id_family, l.level
            FROM  level_families lf
                    JOIN levels l
                    ON lf.id_levels=l.id_levels
        ) t
    ON f.id_family=t.id_family;
```

Comment: try to use `ansi-sql` joins

Comment: Thanks Dhirendra, this returned the following:

Elementary    Hobbies
Elementary    School
Beginner        Hobbies

Any idea how I can get it to output:

Elementry    Hobbies, school
Beginner      Hobbies

Comment: I don,t understand how you want your output..??

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL retrieved the result set I wanted, small issue with ordering but the data is there in the columns.

```
Select Distinct
    levels.Level As Level,
    Group_Concat(families.Family, ', ') As Families
From
    levels Inner Join
    level_families On levels.id_levels = level_families.id_levels Inner Join
    families On families.id_family = level_families.id_family
Group By
    levels.Level
```

### Data Produced

Beginner: Work, Hobbies

Elementary: Hobbies